# Merge values into a while loop

Tags: php, merge

below I have values and below that I have a while loop with multiple values that are sorted by $top_list_friends['workouts'], with the highest number at top.

How can a merge the below values into one list?

```
 echo "<div class='user'>";
 echo "<span class='number'>" . $my_rank . "</span>";
 echo "<span class='name'>" . $personal['name'] . "</span>";
 echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $personal['workouts'] . "</span>";
 echo "</div>";

 $i = 0;                                                                                                                  
 while ($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends)) {
 $i++;

 echo "<div class='user'>";
 echo "<span class='number'>" . $i . "</span>";
 echo "<span class='name'>" . $top_list_friends['name'] . "</span>";
 echo "<span class='workouts'>" . $top_list_friends['workouts'] . "</span>";
 echo "</div>";             
 }
```

Comment: This library `mysql_` is old stuff. Update

Comment: you want to merge `$top_list_friends['name']` and `$top_list_friends['workouts']`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Didn't understand question very well, but I would do it in this way:

```
    $name = $personal['name'];
    $workouts = $personal['workouts'];
    $html = <<<html
        <div class='user'>
        <span class='number'>$my_rank</span>
        <span class='name'>$name</span>
        <span class='workouts'>$workouts</span>
        </div>
html;

     $i=0;                                                                                                               
     while ($top_list_friends = mysql_fetch_array($query_top_list_friends)) {
     $i++;
     $topName = top_list_friends['name'];
     $topW = $top_list_friends['workouts']
     $html += <<<html
         <div class='user'>
         <span class='number'>$i</span>
         <span class='name'>$topName</span>
         <span class='workouts'>$topW</span>
         </div>
html;
    } 
    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning:

```
$inserted=0;
```

into the loop:

```
if(!$inserted && $personal['workouts']> $top_list_friends['workouts'])}
     $inserted=0;
    //first div echoes

}
```

at the end

```
if(!$inserted){

  //the same echos

}
```